# A non vanishing function has an nth root

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $V$ is a simply connected domain, then will any  continuous function $f:V\to\mathbb{C}$ with no zeros in $V$ have a continuous $n^{th}$ root?

Now, if the function were holomorphic, then we could use the existence of $\frac{f'}{f}$ and the chain rule to get a logarithm of $f$, from which we can get the n-th root. But, will any non-vanishing fucntion do? And what if the domain is not simply connected? Will we have an easy counterexample? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Are you at least starting with a continuous function and asking for a continuous $n$th root?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, for othrwise the root will be noncontionuous hence not holomrphic right?

Comment: Your question is highly confusing. You seem to dismiss the holomorphic question and ask a more general question, which was never well-posed.

Comment: @TedShifrin edited, thanks.

Comment: Not edited well enough. You're now asking if a continuous function has a holomorphic $n$th root.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, so you mean like, if $g^n=f$, then $f$ must be holomorphic right? Again edited. But this time, I retain the generality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on a simply connected domain every (continuous) nonvanishing function has a logarithm and hence an $n^{th}$ root for every $n$. The point is that if $V$ is simply connected then, intuitively, a continuous function $f : V \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ can't "wrap around" $0$; formally, the induced map on $\pi_1$ vanishes which implies that $f$ lifts to the universal cover $\exp : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which says exactly that $f$ has a logarithm.

We can also get this result using the [exponential sheaf sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sheaf_sequence) (which makes sense for continuous or smooth or holomorphic functions), which tells us that the obstruction to a map $f \in H^0(V, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ lifting to a map $\tilde{f} \in H^0(V, \mathbb{C})$ is its image under the connecting homomorphism

$$\partial f \in H^1(V, 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(V), \mathbb{Z}) \cong 0$$

which vanishes because $V$ is simply connected; this argument shows moreover that it suffices to assume only that $H^1(V) = 0$ (which is also enough in the previous argument, since this would also imply that the induced map on $\pi_1$ vanishes).

The same argument applied to the Kummer sequence

$$1 \to \mu_n \to \mathbb{C}^{\times} \xrightarrow{z \mapsto z^n} \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to 1$$

(where $\mu_n$ is the group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity) shows a sharper result: that the obstruction to a map $f \in H^0(V, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ admitting an $n^{th}$ root $\tilde{f} \in H^0(V, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is its image under the connecting homomorphism

$$\partial f \in H^1(V, \mu_n) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(V), \mathbb{Z}/n)$$

so for an $n^{th}$ root to exist it suffices that every map $\pi_1(V) \to \mathbb{Z}/n$ be zero (which happens e.g. if $\pi_1(V)$ is torsion and all its torsion has order relatively prime to $n$).

If $V$ isn't simply connected we have the universal counterexample given by $V = \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $f : V \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ the identity map.

Comment: thanks, can there be a proof without the use of algebraic topology?

Comment: @vidyarthi: I don't see how we can expect to avoid algebraic topology since "simply connected" is one of the hypotheses and you aren't working with holomorphic functions so holomorphic tools aren't available either. What do you have left then?

Comment: I guess in the $C^1$ case we can still define the log by integrating $df/f$, but still need Green's Theorem to know this is well-defined by simple-connectivity.

Comment: but, will not the identity map satisfy $e^{\log z}=z$ in $\mathbb{C}^{X}$?

Comment: @vidyarthi: the whole point of this discussion is that "$\log z$" is not well-defined globally.